# How to recover the gpg secret key?

Tags: gnupg, gpg-signature

I am using a new computer, but my gpg secret key is in another computer which is broken, so I can not import it from there. Then how can I find back the the secret key ? Thanks

Comment: If the hard-disk is broken, say good bye Alice to the private key. You had a backup right? I always keep my private keys backed up on pendrives.

Comment: I have mac time machine disk, but didn't export the private key. Is it possible to recover it from this time machine disk.